# Malloc causes crashing when used in JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

When I am trying to malloc and pass structure to the native library function my app crashes, without malloc there is no issues and if not calling the native library function it is not crashing. Please help me on this.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_tvgui_List_dataFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject instance,jint size, jobjectArray foo) {
DTV_STRUCT1 *data_info;

data_info = (DTV_STRUCT1*)malloc(sizeof(DTV_STRUCT1));
    if(data_info == NULL){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG","malloc Failed\n");
        return;
    }

    /*This call causes crash*/
    dtv_get_data(0,data_info);


free(data_info);
}
```

```
> **ERROR :**android invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x70cb08c8 passed to dlfree 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: FATAL ERROR occurring at line:
> 4678
>     least_addr: 0x31b56000, mchunkptr: 0x70cd5208. Segment Infomation: 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc:         base    : 
> size 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc:   000
> 70a41000:  4055040 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui
> A/libc: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP INFO *** *** *** *** *** ***
> *** 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: chunk ptr 0x70cd5208(p), cinuse(0), pinuse(0), chunksize(0) 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc:   70cd5208:  00000000  prev_foot
>       70cd520c:  00000000  head
>       70cd5210:  00000000  fd
>       70cd5214:  00000000  bk 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP
> INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: chunk ptr p->fd is invalid with
> any segment 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: ***
> *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: chunk ptr p->bk is
> invalid with any segment 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP
> INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: chunk ptr 0x70cd5208(prev),
> cinuse(0), pinuse(0), chunksize(0) 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc:   70cd5208:  00000000  prev_foot
>       70cd520c:  00000000  head
>       70cd5210:  00000000  fd
>       70cd5214:  00000000  bk 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP
> INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: chunk ptr "next" is invalid with
> any segment 06-28 14:46:19.849 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc:
> heap corruption detected by dlmalloc 06-28 14:46:19.849
> 6519-6519/com.example.tvgui A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at
> 0x00001977 (code=-6), thread 6519 (m.example.tvgui)
```

Comment: looks like a memory corruption, if you just leave malloc and free, does it crash?

Comment: NO it wont crash, it crashes only when calling the Native library function

Comment: If the crash happens inside `dtv_get_data()`, we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlexCohn It is occuring at libC

Comment: It looks like dtv_get_data  (and therefore libc) is expecting that block of memory to have be initialised.

Comment: The easiest way to reproduce such crash would be to change some value at `data_info-1`.